# What is the difference b/w potential energy and interaction energy in electrostatics?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

These two terms were given under the same portion in my book. I don't understand these perfectly. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Please provide the exact statement

Comment: Which book? Which page?